# Program automatically ending after if statement

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I am creating a chess program and I'm creating a feature where if you are in check, a voice says 'check'.

Here is my code (the main file, anyways):

```
import pygame as p
import ChessEngine
import pyttsx3


WIDTH = HEIGHT = 512
DIMENSION = 8
SQ_SIZE = HEIGHT//DIMENSION
MAX_FPS = 15
IMAGES = {}


def loadImages():
    pieces = ['wp', 'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wK',
              'wQ', 'bp', 'bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bK', 'bQ']
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = p.transform.scale(
            p.image.load('Chess/Images/' + piece + '.png'), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def main():
    p.init()
    screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(p.Color("white"))

    global CheckV
    gs = ChessEngine.GameState()
    validMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
    moveMade = False
    animate = False
    loadImages()
    running = True
    sqSelected = ()
    playerClicks = []
    gameOver = False
    CheckV = False
    while running:
        for e in p.event.get():
            if e.type == p.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif e.type == p.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if not gameOver:
                    location = p.mouse.get_pos()
                    col = location[0]//SQ_SIZE
                    row = location[1]//SQ_SIZE
                    if sqSelected == (row, col):
                        sqSelected = ()
                        playerClicks = []
                    else:
                        sqSelected = (row, col)
                        playerClicks.append(sqSelected)
                    if len(playerClicks) == 2:
                        move = ChessEngine.Move(
                            playerClicks[0], playerClicks[1], gs.board)
                        for i in range(len(validMoves)):
                            if move == validMoves[i]:
                                gs.makeMove(validMoves[i])
                                moveMade = True
                                animate = True
                                sqSelected = ()
                                playerClicks = []
                        if not moveMade:
                            playerClicks = [sqSelected]

            elif e.type == p.KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == p.K_z:
                    gs.undoMove()
                    moveMade = True
                    animate = False
                    checkMate = False
                    staleMate = False
                    gameOver = False
                if e.key == p.K_r:
                    gs = ChessEngine.GameState()
                    validMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
                    sqSelected = ()
                    playerClicks = []
                    moveMade = False
                    animate = False
                    checkMate = False
                    staleMate = False
                    gameOver = False

        if moveMade:
            if animate:
                animateMove(gs.moveLog[-1], screen, gs.board, clock)
            validMoves = gs.getValidMoves()

            if gs.inCheck():
                CheckV = True

            if CheckV == True:
                pyttsx3.speak('check')
                CheckV = False

            moveMade = False
            animate = False

        drawGameState(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected)

        if gs.checkMate:
            gameOver = True
            if gs.whitetoMove:
                drawText(screen, ' Black wins by Checkmate')
            else:
                drawText(screen, ' White wins by Checkmate')
        elif gs.staleMate:
            gameOver = True
            drawText(screen, 'Stalemate')

        clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
        p.display.flip()


def highlightSquares(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected):
    if sqSelected != ():
        r, c = sqSelected
        if gs.board[r][c][0] == ('w' if gs.whitetoMove else 'b'):
            s = p.Surface((SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
            s.set_alpha(100)
            s.fill(p.Color('blue'))
            screen.blit(s, (c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE))
            s.fill(p.Color('yellow'))
            for move in validMoves:
                if move.startRow == r and move.startCol == c:
                    screen.blit(s, (SQ_SIZE*move.endCol, SQ_SIZE*move.endRow))


def drawGameState(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected):
    drawBoard(screen)
    highlightSquares(screen, gs, validMoves, sqSelected)
    drawPieces(screen, gs.board)


def drawBoard(screen):
    global colors
    colors = [p.Color("white"), p.Color("gray")]
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            color = colors[((r+c) % 2)]
            p.draw.rect(screen, color, p.Rect(
                c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def drawPieces(screen, board):
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            piece = board[r][c]
            if piece != "--":
                screen.blit(IMAGES[piece], p.Rect(
                    c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def animateMove(move, screen, board, clock):
    global colors
    dR = move.endRow - move.startRow
    dC = move.endCol - move.startCol
    framesPerSquare = 10
    frameCount = (abs(dR) + abs(dC)) * framesPerSquare
    for frame in range(frameCount + 1):
        p.event.pump()
        r, c = (move.startRow + dR * frame / frameCount,
                move.startCol + dC*frame / frameCount)
        drawBoard(screen)
        drawPieces(screen, board)
        color = colors[(move.endRow + move.endCol) % 2]
        endSquare = p.Rect(move.endCol*SQ_SIZE,
                           move.endRow*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE)
        p.draw.rect(screen, color, endSquare)
        if move.pieceCaptured != '--':
            screen.blit(IMAGES[move.pieceCaptured], endSquare)
        screen.blit(IMAGES[move.pieceMoved], p.Rect(
            c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
        p.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


def drawText(screen, text):
    font = p.font.SysFont("Helvetica", 32, True, False)
    textObject = font.render(text, 0, p.Color('Gray'))
    textLocation = p.Rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT).move(
        WIDTH/2 - textObject.get_width()/2, HEIGHT/2 - textObject.get_height()/2)
    screen.blit(textObject, textLocation)
    textObject = font.render(text, 0,  p.Color("Black"))
    screen.blit(textObject, textLocation.move(2, 2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Specifically these lines:

```
if gs.inCheck():
                CheckV = True

            if CheckV == True:
                pyttsx3.speak('check')
                CheckV = False
```

I do not get an error, however after the voice, the code automatically ends instead of just continuing like I want it to. Is there anyway to do this which I have overlooked? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is due to the `if` statement.  Have you tried commenting out the `.speak()` call to see if that's the problem?

Comment: Yes, it is now working, I am able to print out the statement.

Comment: Ok, I have changed the .speak to os.system("say ' ' ") and its working now.